# Inner Join returning wrong number of results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My query is returning 54 rows when it should return 59. I feel like I only need the Inner join because I wouldn't want to include NULL values in my results. I've also tried doing Left Outer Joins to filter out some of the non matching values but it returns too many results (62). I'm using DISTINCT so Duplicates shouldn't be the issue.

The query I'm trying to Create:

"List all ingredient classes and the titles of any recipes that use at least one
ingredient of that class, if any. Eliminate all duplicates. (2 columns, 59 rows)"

My Code:

```
select DISTINCT Ingredients.IngredientClassID, Recipes.RecipeTitle
from Ingredients
Inner join Recipe_Ingredients on Ingredients.IngredientID = 
Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
Inner join Recipes on Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID = Recipes.RecipeID;
```

[Link to a DB Fiddle I setup](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4045ed03542e2ffa19e5d431fa0849e)

Diagram of Database: 
[image]

Comment: Why are you expecting 54 rows? do you have exactly 54 lines in the Recipe-Ingridients table? I would recommend adding more columns, and seeing if you indeed query what you expected. BTW - your design is a little off - Recipe_Ingredients is a classic many-to-many connection - it should be ID (identity(1,1)), RecipeId (int FK) and IngredientId (int FK). Both should be not nullable.

Answer (score 1):

I think 54 rows is the correct output. My query gave the same number of rows.

```
FROM Ingredient_Classes ic
    LEFT JOIN Ingredients i ON i.IngredientClassID = ic.IngredientClassID
    LEFT JOIN Recipe_Ingredients ri ON ri.ingredientId = i.ingredientId
    JOIN recipes r ON r.recipeid = ri.recipeId
WHERE i.ingredientId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ic.IngredientClassDescription, r.recipetitle
ORDER BY recipetitle;
```

You can select distinct(recipe.title) and see that all recipes are present in the output. So I don't think we missed anything.